# Why isn't a cemetery a public domain for the laws of tumah?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

[Tohorot 3:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Tahorot.3.7) explains why, when it comes to tumah, we are lenient in the case of a child found "to the side of a cemetery" (namely because he can't be interrogated).
My question is, though, why isn't the answer even simpler: that he's in a public area, and we always rule leniently in a public area when it comes to tumah?

None of the commentators seem to address this, except for Tiferet Yisrael who [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Yachin_on_Mishnah_Tahorot.3.39?lang=bi) that the cemetery is a private area given that nobody else is around. But even this isn't right, surely, because when it comes to tumah, public/ private areas are defined not by whether or not anyone *is* around but whether or not it's the sort of place where people might *generally* be around. Is a cemetery not exactly the sort of place where people might generally be around?

So basically my question is: why isn't a cemetery a public domain for the laws of tumah?

Comment: Why do you think a cemetery is a place people might generally be around? Cemeteries are usually very empty of people in my experience

Comment: @DoubleAA Really? I don't think I've ever once seen a Jewish cemetery without at least a few people attending a funeral, tending graves, visiting the graves of deceased relatives etc.

Comment: you must live in a giant Jewish metropolis (Jerusalem? Brooklyn?). Go to a city with a Jewish population the size of a medieval town and look there

Comment: @DoubleAA London, actually, but nonetheless, is a cemetery not the sort of place where people are accustomed to gather? Ie it has frequent events (funerals) to no set timetable? Even treacherous mountain paths are counted as such a place - Tohorot 6:6 - so why would a village cemetery not be?

Comment: @Zarka But who says that funerals were that frequent? I have a book on Roman history (lehavdil), where the author mentions that while it was common for babies and children to die of various illnesses, "adult funerals were relatively rare events" - and the same demographic trends were likely the case among Jews as well. (The mourning rites - עומדים בשורה, etc. - didn't necessarily take place in the cemetery itself, and a child's coffin is just ניטלת באגפיים by one person.)

Comment: @Meir This is very true, but I guessI just struggle to see that the presence of a living person in a cemetery could possibly have been *less* frequent than the presence of a living person on a remote mountain path?

Comment: @Zarka Sure, but it's not just one living person - you need three to make it a reshus harabbim. By contrast, people generally didn't travel alone back then (too much danger from wild animals or bandits), so when they were going to use such paths to get to and from Gilgal, they might well go in a group.

Comment: @Zarka But that would also apply to a cemetery no? People would tend not to go on their own but rather in a work detail or in a funeral party?

Comment: @Zarka Cemeteries weren't necessarily that far out of the city (halachah requires them to be only 50 amos away), so it wouldn't have been particularly dangerous to go there alone, unlike intercity paths.

Comment: @Zarka I’m not suggesting they’d only go there in groups out of fear. More out of practicality. At least three people at a funeral. At least a handful of workers tending to it once a year. Etc.